# Handling multiple api calls with Promis.all and manipulating the data with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I am building an app with react/ redux for managing Collection of Electronic equipment (=donations).
In the first stage I need to make 2 api calls:
the first and the second are donations data and donors data (kept as different collections in mongodb) and then combine them. This info is shown in a donation route.
The action looks like this:

```
const basicUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
export const requestDonor_DonationData = () => getDonationData (
    `${basicUrl}/donor`, 
    `${basicUrl}/donation`
);
```

and the getDonationData func looks like this:

```
import {
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING,
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES,
    REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED
} from './constants';
 

export const getDonationData = (urlDonor, urlDonation) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ( {type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING} );
    Promise.all([
        fetch(urlDonor).then(res => res.json()),
        fetch(urlDonation).then(res => res.json())
     ]).then ( ([ donorResult, donationResult]) => donorResult.data.map( (e, i) =>  Object.assign(e, donationResult.data[i]) ) )
        .then( mergedData => dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES, payload: mergedData }) )
        .catch(error => dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED, payload: error}) ) 
}
```

that works fine.

In the second stage, When a donation have been peeked up, it become an equipment (not the perfect word..) which means that now it is waiting for inspection. this info is shown in a equipment route.
the equipment data contain the donationId and status (different from the donation status).
Now I want to do something similar:

1. make 3 api calls (getting donor, donation, & equipment data)
2. merging the donor whit its donation data
3. filtering the merged
   data with the donations that have been peeked up (status='DONE')
4. create a new json which takes the merged data and replace the ID and
   status of donation with the ID and status of the equipment.

I tried
to do that with the first approach (just with Promise.all) but found
it very confusing working with multiple ".then" ...

this is what I tried :
the action-

```
export const requestEquipmentData = () => getEquipmentData ( 
    [
    `${basicUrl}/donor`, 
    `${basicUrl}/donation`,
    `${basicUrl}/equipment`
    ]
);

export const getEquipmentData = (urls) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ( {type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING} );
    try {
        const [ donorResult, donationResult, equipmentResult ] =  Promise.all(urls.map(async function(url) {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            return response.json();
        }));
        const donationInfo =  donorResult.data.map( (e, i) => Object.assign(e, donationResult.data[i]) );
        const filteredDonation = donationInfo.filter(item =>item.status==='DONE');
        const equipment =  filteredDonation.map( (donation,i) => {
                let obj = donation;
                obj.id = equipmentResult.data[i].id;
                obj.status = equipmentResult.data[i].status;   
                return obj;
        })
        dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES, payload: equipment });

    }  catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED, payload: error})
    }
}
```

but I am doing somethig wrong, and that is the error:

```
type: "REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED", payload: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You may be calling `dispatch` in file you don't have access to it. Try to console log it and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `Promise.all()` is a `Promise` that resolves to the `array` of results.  It is not an array itself so you cannot destructure it like this.

You can use the same `.then()` approach that you used in your first example:

```
export const getEquipmentData = (urls) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING });
    Promise.all(urls.map(async function (url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return response.json();
    })).then(([donorResult, donationResult, equipmentResult]) => {
        const donationInfo = donorResult.data.map((e, i) => Object.assign(e, donationResult.data[i]));
        const filteredDonation = donationInfo.filter(item => item.status === 'DONE');
        const equipment = filteredDonation.map((donation, i) => {
            let obj = donation;
            obj.id = equipmentResult.data[i].id;
            obj.status = equipmentResult.data[i].status;
            return obj;
        })
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES, payload: equipment });
    }).catch(error) {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED, payload: error })
    }
}
```

Or you can use `async`/`await` syntax.  [Checkout this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/10431574) for a generally discussion on resolving an array of Promises.

```
export const getEquipmentData = (urls) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ( {type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_PENDING} );
    try {
        const [ donorResult, donationResult, equipmentResult ] =  await Promise.all(urls.map(async function(url) {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            return response.json();
        }));
        const donationInfo =  donorResult.data.map( (e, i) => Object.assign(e, donationResult.data[i]) );
        const filteredDonation = donationInfo.filter(item =>item.status==='DONE');
        const equipment =  filteredDonation.map( (donation,i) => {
                let obj = donation;
                obj.id = equipmentResult.data[i].id;
                obj.status = equipmentResult.data[i].status;   
                return obj;
        })
        dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_SUCCES, payload: equipment });

    }  catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: REQUEST_ENTITIES_FAILED, payload: error})
    }
}
```

---

In my opinion your general approach here is not good.  You should read the guides on [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).  It seems like your APIs are returning normalized data and then your are "unnormalizing" it by combining data from multiple endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I missed the async await with the second approach, and with the first approach I were not aware to that urls: string[].

you are right about the api's - it was not my decision to design them like this, the reason for that design as i been told is for reason of Producing reports,
anyway I will explore it,
thank again for the detailed answer!!

Comment: Oh! that `urls: string[]` is an accident.  I write code in Typescript and I forgot to remove the type!